# pytest & pytest-benchmark: serial or parallel?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-benchmark

1. In a single file: `test.py`, I have 3 test functions: `test1()`, `test2()`, `test3()`. Does `pytest` and `pytest-benchmark` run these 3 test cases in parallel or in serial?
2. I have 3 files: `test1.py`, `test2.py`, `test3.py`. Respectively, I have a single test function in each file: `test1()`, `test2()`, `test3()`. Are these 3 tests run in parallel or in serial, if I simply run `pytest` or `pytest-benchmark` in the directory they are in?

Comment: Neither `pytest` nor `pytest-benchmark` run anything in parallel, everything is executed sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [responses from crosspost](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/c2bmze/pytest_pytestbenchmark_serial_or_parallel/) on Reddit and the comments above,

`pytest` and `pytest-benchmark` always run in serial.

Answer (score 0):

pytest and pytest-benchmark always run in serial .
can run the file from main folder terminal
[This](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-benchmark/) will help you